# Why is there a yellow bar over my Finder icon?

Tags: finder, dock, graphics, icon

I have a Mac running OS X El Capitan (10.11.3), and I just noticed this today:

[image: Weird Finder Icon]

I haven't installed anything new, and I have no reason to believe that there's a specific application responsible for this issue. I rebooted my Mac, cleared the NVRAM and ran CleanMyMac 3, but it's still there. Killing the dock or restarting `SystemUIServer` doesn't help.

**Question:** Why is there a yellow bar over my Finder icon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a corrupt icon cache. It can be fixed by running the following code from [fabiofl](https://gist.github.com/fabiofl/5873100):

```
sudo find /private/var/folders/ -name com.apple.dock.iconcache -exec rm {} \;
```